# TikZ: rotating a pic of nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

A friend showed a quilt pattern on which they were working. Ah, I said, I could easily do that in Ti*k*Z with `pic`s. Well, yes and no: Do it, certainly; easily, not so much. I have the  `pic` shown below, as well as the finished pattern which was done completely by brute force. There must be a way to do this more efficiently, and in a way that could be generalized for other patters.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[papersize={5.5in,8.5in},margin=0.6in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\tikzset{%
    dartstyle/.style={kite,draw,kite vertex angles=60,inner sep=0.125in,outer sep=0pt,fill=#1},
    pics/quiltdart/.style={%
        code={%
          \node[dartstyle=red](base) {};
          \node[rotate=0,dartstyle=white,anchor=upper vertex] at (base.right vertex) {};
          \node[rotate=0,dartstyle=white,anchor=upper vertex] at (base.left vertex) {};
          \node[rotate=0,dartstyle=red,anchor=upper vertex] at (base.lower vertex) {};
        }%
    }%
}

\parindent0pt

\begin{document}

This was easy:

\tikz \pic {quiltdart};

\bigskip

This, not so much\dots

\tikz {\pic {quiltdart};
    \pic[yshift=-0.51in,xshift=0.89in,rotate=-60,transform shape]  {quiltdart};
    \pic[yshift=-1.54in,xshift=0.89in,rotate=-120,transform shape]  {quiltdart};
    \pic[yshift=-2.05in,xshift=-0in,rotate=-180,transform shape]  {quiltdart};
    \pic[yshift=-1.54in,xshift=-0.89in,rotate=-240,transform shape]  {quiltdart};
    \pic[yshift=-0.51in,xshift=-0.89in,rotate=-300,transform shape]  {quiltdart};
}

\end{document}
```

[image: quilt image]

## Update

First, I want to thank those who have replied to my post: I have learned an enormous amount. For that reason, I am posting this as an **Update** rather than an **Answer** because it would not have been possible without the thought-provoking replies from which I do not in any way wish to detract.

Here is my approach. It works nicely though it is probably not the most efficient code possible. On the other hand it is straightforward and easily maintained/tinkered-with.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage[margin=1.4in,top=0.5in,left=0.75in]{geometry}

\NewDocumentCommand{\makeshape}{m}{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myhuei}{rnd}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myhueii}{rnd}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myhueiii}{rnd}
    \definecolor{mycolori}{hsb}{\myhuei,1,1}
    \definecolor{mycolorii}{hsb}{\myhueii,0.25,1}
    \definecolor{mycoloriii}{hsb}{\myhueiii,1,1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\lang}{180/#1}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\bang}{90-\lang}%
    \tikzset{%
        pics/dart/.style={code={%
            \draw[fill=mycolorii] (0,0) -- ++(90-\lang:2) --
                ++(180-\bang:2) -- ++(-90-\lang:2) -- cycle;
            \draw[fill=mycolori](0,0) -- ++(90-\lang:1) -- ++(180 - \bang:1)coordinate(T) --
                ++(-90-\lang:1) -- cycle;
            \draw[fill=mycoloriii](T) -- ++(90-\lang:1) -- ++(-180 - \bang:1) --
                ++(-90-\lang:1)-- cycle;
            }%
        },%
    }%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=\lang,scale=0.5]%% both rotate and scale can be altered to suit
        \foreach \i [count=\ii from 0] in {1,...,#1}
            \path pic[rotate around={360/#1*\ii:(0,0)},transform shape]{dart};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\parindent0pt

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\foreach \N in {4,5,...,18}{\makeshape{\N}}

\end{document}
```

[image: samples new update]

Comment: Note that there is an easier way of using pic without nodes, in this case

Comment: A herd of elephants, a pack of wolves, a swarm of bees, a shoal of fish and a pic of nodes.

Comment: Ah. An example of venereal Ti*k*Z!!

Comment: There was a small piece of superfluous code in my **Update**. That has been fixed.

Comment: @sgmoye What is the meaning of the third color (the between one)?

Comment: As a quick visual indicator that there are 3 shapes used. And it was fun.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a somewhat improvement by using a `\foreach` statement and replacing the `rotate` option by `rotate around`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[papersize={5.5in,8.5in},margin=0.6in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\tikzset{%
    dartstyle/.style={kite,draw,kite vertex angles=60,inner sep=0.125in,outer sep=0pt,fill=#1},
    pics/quiltdart/.style={%
        code={%
          \node[dartstyle=red](base) {};
          \node[rotate=0,dartstyle=white,anchor=upper vertex] at (base.right vertex) {};
          \node[rotate=0,dartstyle=white,anchor=upper vertex] at (base.left vertex) {};
          \node[rotate=0,dartstyle=red,anchor=upper vertex] 
                at (base.lower vertex)(bottom dart){}; % <-----
        }%
    }%
}

\parindent0pt

\begin{document}

This was easy:

\tikz \pic {quiltdart};

\bigskip

What about this ???


\begin{tikzpicture}
 \foreach \i in {0,60,...,300}{
  \pic[rotate around={\i:(bottom dart.lower vertex)},
      transform shape] {quiltdart};
  }

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**An other solution** by modifying the pic code so that the origin of the  pic corresponds to the lowest vertex:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[papersize={5.5in,8.5in},margin=0.6in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\tikzset{%
    dartstyle/.style={kite,draw,kite vertex angles=60,inner sep=0.125in,outer sep=0pt,fill=#1},
    pics/quiltdart/.style={%
        code={%
          \node[dartstyle=red,anchor=lower vertex](base) {};
          \node[dartstyle=white,anchor=left vertex] at (base.upper vertex) {};
          \node[dartstyle=white,anchor=right vertex] at (base.upper vertex) {};
          \node[dartstyle=red,anchor=lower vertex] at (base.upper vertex){};
        }%
    }%
}

\parindent0pt

\begin{document}

%This was easy:

%\tikz \pic {quiltdart};

%\bigskip

%This, not so much\dots


\begin{tikzpicture}

% first copy
\foreach \i in {0,60,...,300}{
\pic[rotate =\i,transform shape] {quiltdart};
}
% second copy
\foreach \i in {0,60,...,300}{
\pic[rotate =\i,transform shape] at(0,8){quiltdart};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very interesting. I've not used `rotate around` before and it seems very handy. I take it that using `rotate around` in the options to the `\pic` allows reference to the named dart, also a revelation. I've learned something!

Comment: Made an interesting and unexpected discovery. When I deleted the first instance of `\tikz\pic{quiltdart}` (following 'This was easy;') and ran your code, I received an error: `No shape named `bottom dart' is known.` Changing your code to `\pic{quiltdart} \foreach \i in {60,120,...,300)...` fixed the problem. I can only imagine that using  the command`\tikz` as opposed to `\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}, thus avoiding grouping, allowed the second use of `\pic{quiltdart} to succeed. Interesting. So I was wrong about my original thought about the named dart.

Comment: @sgmoye answer updated! the command  `\tikz` and  the environment `tikzpicture` are essentially the same. The problem was that the `coordinate` "named bottom dart" is only created after the use of the pic in which it is defined. I update my answer with little changes to the pic code so that the origin corresponds to position of the lowest vertex.

Answer (score 15):

With just a `path`, without `pics` or `nodes`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[papersize={5.5in,8.5in},margin=0.6in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\mydart}[1][]{
    \filldraw[black, fill=red, even odd rule,#1] (0,0)--++(60:1)--++(120:1)--++(240:1)--cycle (60:.5)--++(60:.5)--++(120:.5)--++(240:1)--++(120:.5)--++(60:.5)--cycle
}

\begin{document}

This was easy:

\tikz \mydart;

\bigskip

What about this ???

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \foreach \i in {0,60,...,300}{
  \mydart[rotate around={\i:(0,0)}];
  }

\end{tikzpicture}


or this ???

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \foreach \i in {0,60,...,300}{
  \mydart[shift={(\i:1)}, rotate=\i];
  }

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 13):

This is another approach, changing the `pic`. In my `pic` I draw four squares, but I changed the axes to 'deform' them.

Like this:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}

\definecolor{color0}{HTML}{FFFFFF} % white
\definecolor{color1}{HTML}{FF0000} % red

\tikzset
{%
  pics/quiltdart/.style={
    code={%
      \pgfmathsetmacro\y{sin(60)}
      \begin{scope}[x={(0.5 cm,\y cm)}, y={(-0.5 cm,\y cm)}]
        \foreach\i in {0,1} \foreach\j in {0,1}
        {
          \pgfmathtruncatemacro\c{Mod(\i+\j+1,2)}
          \draw[fill=color\c] (\i,\j) -- (\i,\j+1) -- (\i+1,\j+1) -- (\i+1,\j) -- cycle;
        } 
      \end{scope}
    }},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round]
\foreach\a in {0,60,...,300}
  \pic[rotate=\a] {quiltdart};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'll need to meditate on this for a while...

Answer (score 9):

Compile with [Asymptote](https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/) or at http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/

```
size(5cm);

picture pic;
unitsize(pic,1cm);

path g=(0,0)--0.5*dir(60)--0.5*dir(0)--0.5*dir(-60)--cycle;
draw(pic,g^^shift(0.5*dir(0))*g);
filldraw(pic,shift(0.5*dir(60))*g^^shift(0.5*dir(-60))*g,red,black);

for (int i=0;i<6;++i)
  add(rotate(i*60,dir(-60))*pic);
```

If you can any issues with my code, please comment.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

**New solution**

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{quiltdart/.pic={%
\def\n{#1} % the number of quiltdart
% random colors from OP
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myhuei}{rnd}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myhueii}{rnd}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myhueiii}{rnd}
\definecolor{mycolori}{hsb}{\myhuei,1,1}
\definecolor{mycolorii}{hsb}{\myhueii,0.25,1}
\definecolor{mycoloriii}{hsb}{\myhueiii,1,1}
        
\def\basicdart{(0,0)--(90-360/\n:1)--+(0,1)--(0,1)--cycle}          
\foreach \i in {0,...,\n}{
\draw[fill=mycoloriii,rotate=\i*360/\n,shift={(90-360/\n:1)},shift={(0,1)}] \basicdart;
\draw[fill=mycolori,rotate=\i*360/\n] \basicdart;
\draw[fill=mycolorii,rotate=\i*360/\n,shift={(0,1)}] \basicdart;
\draw[fill=mycolorii,rotate=\i*360/\n,shift={(0,1)},xscale=-1] \basicdart;
}
}}

\newcounter{myquilt}
\setcounter{myquilt}{2} 
\foreach \j in {1,...,5}
\foreach \i in {1,...,8}
{\stepcounter{myquilt}
\path (6*\i,-6*\j) pic[scale=.6]{quiltdart=\themyquilt} 
% +(-90:2.6) node{$n=$ \themyquilt}   % show the number of quiltdart
;
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Old solutions**
I guess the essential issue is centering/not centering `pic`, neither `pic of nodes` nor `rotate`. This turns to quite interesting situations:

- `pic` is/is not centered at the origin (name `dart`)
- `pic` of `pic`s (name `quiltdart`).

I add the default values for parameters of the `pic`s. The option `[rotate,shift]` is used instead of `[rotate around]`. I hope the code and the pictures are self-exlpained.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}
% Multi-parameters pic with default
\tikzset{
pics/dart/.style args={#1 and #2}{code={%
\draw[fill=#1] (-120:1)--(60:1)--([turn]60:1)--(120:1)--(-60:1)--([turn]-60:1)--cycle;
\draw[fill=#2] (-120:1)--(60:1)--(0:1)--(-60:1)--(120:1)--(180:1)--cycle;
}},
pics/dart/.default={red and white}
}

% Multi-parameters pic of pics with default
\tikzset{pics/quiltdart/.style args={#1 and #2}{code={%
\foreach \i in {0,...,5}
\path (0,0) pic[rotate=60*\i,shift={(0,-sqrt(3))}]{dart={#1 and #2}};
}},
pics/quiltdart/.default={red and white}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path 
(0,0) pic{dart} node[above=2.5cm,scale=2]{\verb|\pic{dart}|}
(18,0) pic{dart={magenta and cyan}} node[above=2.5cm,scale=2]{\verb|\pic{dart={magenta and cyan}}|};

\foreach \i in {0,...,5}
\path (0,-10) pic[rotate=60*\i,shift={(0,-sqrt(3))}]{dart};
\path (0,-10) node[above=3.5cm,scale=2,align=center]{Good\\
    \verb|\foreach \i in {0,...,5}|\\
    \verb|\pic[rotate=60*\i,shift={(0,-sqrt(3))}]{dart}|};
\path 
(18,-10) pic{quiltdart={magenta and cyan}} node[above=3.5cm,scale=2,align=center]{Better\\
    \verb|\pic{quiltdart={magenta and cyan}}|};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Some examples of quilt decorations**

1. A tiling of the plane

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {0,...,5}
\foreach \j in {0,...,4}
\path (5*\i,-5*\j) pic{quiltdart};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

2. A green quilt

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {0,...,5}
\foreach \j in {0,...,4}
\path (8*\i,-8*\j) pic{quiltdart={green and white}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

**Update Asymptote version** `pic` of `pic`s can be translated from TikZ to Asymptote.

[image]

```
unitsize(1cm);

// creating dart
picture dart;
unitsize(dart,1cm);
path p=dir(-120)--dir(60)--dir(0)--dir(-60)--dir(120)--dir(180)--cycle;
path q=dir(-120)--dir(60)--sqrt(3)*dir(90)--dir(120)--dir(-60)--sqrt(3)*dir(-90)--cycle;
filldraw(dart,p,pink,black);
filldraw(dart,q,purple,black);

// creating quiltdart from darts
picture quiltdart;
unitsize(quiltdart,1cm);
for(int i=0;i<6;++i)
add(quiltdart,rotate(i*60)*shift(0,-sqrt(3))*dart);

// Here is the quilt
for (int i=0;i<6;++i)
for (int j=0;j<3;++j)
add(shift(8*i,-8*j)*quiltdart);

shipout(bbox(1cm,invisible));
```

**Update 2: General case** A generalization of n-point-star quiltdarts. Sometimes, the general problem is easier to deal with a particular problem. It is how I feel for the situation of the new update answer of OP.

Idea is simple, straight forward of creating a function with parameter `n`. There 3 classes; each class is made from rotations of the basic dart; a small care for the middle class.

**n=20** `quiltdart(20,yellow,magenta,purple);`

[image]

```
// http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
unitsize(1cm);
// the basic dart
path dart(int n){
pair A=(0,0),D=(0,1),B=dir(90-360/n),C=B+D-A;
return A--B--C--D--cycle;
}

// the quiltdart of three classes
void quiltdart(int n, pen innerpen, pen middlepen, pen outerpen){
for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
transform rot=rotate(i*360/n);  
path outerclass=rot*shift((0,1)+dir(90-360/n))*dart(n);
path middleclass1=rot*shift(0,1)*dart(n);
path middleclass2=rot*shift(0,1)*xscale(-1)*dart(n);
path innerclass=rot*dart(n);
filldraw(outerclass,outerpen,black);
filldraw(middleclass1,middlepen,black);
filldraw(middleclass2,middlepen,black);
filldraw(innerclass,innerpen,black);
}} 

quiltdart(20,yellow,magenta,purple);
shipout(bbox(1cm,invisible));
```

**n=4** `quiltdart(4,yellow,orange,green);`

[image]

**n=50** `quiltdart(50,yellow,green,red);`

[image]

**Update 3:** A general solution with TikZ. `n=45` is the maximal number that TikZ/TeX can compile without irritating and throwing up "Dimension too large" error.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\n{45}
\def\basicdart{(0,0)--(90-360/\n:1)--+(0,1)--(0,1)--cycle}          
\foreach \i in {0,...,\n}{
\draw[fill=magenta,rotate=\i*360/\n,shift={(90-360/\n:1)},shift={(0,1)}] \basicdart;
\draw[fill=yellow,rotate=\i*360/\n] \basicdart;
\draw[fill=orange,rotate=\i*360/\n,shift={(0,1)}] \basicdart;
\draw[fill=orange,rotate=\i*360/\n,shift={(0,1)},xscale=-1] \basicdart;
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wonderful! Yes, it was frustrating that the 'pic of nodes' was not centered at the origin. *Drawing* the shapes as opposed to using *nodes* fixes that problem, as you nicely demonstrate.

Comment: @sgmoye Yes, I guess the essential issue is centering/not centering pic, neither `pic of nodes` nor `rotate`.

Comment: I added an Asymptote version for `pic` of `pic`s

Comment: I'm probably being very stupid. In my original post I suggested the possibility of generalizing this: not all darts are 60° (for a star of 6 points) -- some are 72° (5-point star) or indeed an arbitrary number of points, 360°/n. Clearly, in this case, 60 is not merely 360/6 nor is 120 simply 180-360/6. Could you generalize your Ti*k*Z to account for this possibility? So far, I have had no luck :<(

Comment: @sgmoye I am not sure I understand exactly what you describe about 5-point star, 6-point star, ... . Are they made from the darts? Could you describe them more clearly? (as an update of your question)

Comment: @sgmoye please have a look at the general case I have just update (in Asymptote)

Comment: Wonderful! Have never used Asymptote, so this will require some investigation on my part...

Comment: @sgmoye Done! I amm tiredddd offff updatingggg theeee TikZZZ solution, lol. Why would not you ask the general case from the begining?

Comment: From my original post: "There must be a way to do this more efficiently, and in a way that could be generalized for other patterns."

Comment: @sgmoye Never mind! I was just kidding. There is a new update. It made me laughing out loud. Who like to use that quilt of colorful hedgehogs ^^

Answer (score 6):

A trivial solution with PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}

\newcommand\x[1][red]{%
    \pspolygon[fillcolor=#1]
        (0,0)(1,0)(!1 60 PtoC exch 1 add exch)(1;60)}
        
\def\y{%
    \x\rput(1,0){\x[white]}
    \rput(1;60){\x[white]\rput(1,0){\x}}}
    
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[fillstyle=solid](-4,-4)(4,4)
    \foreach \i in {0,60,...,300}{\rput{\i}(0,0){\y}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]